# How to get (hour minute second) from SSML in ALEXA skill kit

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

​I am trying to make SSML for the following date-time  = 2017-12- 22  1: 12 :22

The date is extensively mention in the ALEXA documentation but I am having problem on time. I am unable to figure out how to represent time in hours minute second

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just specify time in standard hh:mm:ss format, no extra formatting needed. So for example, if the above "1: 12 :22" means "one twelve and twenty two seconds", then just specify it as 1:12:22.

Try entering text like that into the Alexa developer console's Test tab Voice Simulator to hear how Alexa will speak something.

Comment: its not working <say-as interpret-as='time'>1:12:22</say-as>

Comment: You don't need the <say-as...
It is possible that your location expects a different format. In the US, just typing "helllo, the time is 1:12:22" into the voice simulator responds correctly. What does the voice simulator speak for you?